# Ich werde vs. Ich werde mich

Tags: verb-usage

On Duolingo was asked to translate "I will not surrender."

So my answer was

```
Ich werde mich nicht aufgeben.
```

But the correct one is:

```
Ich werde nicht aufgeben.
```

Why my answer is wrong? and what is the difference between the two ?

Comment: Just so you know, Duo has it's own forum for questions relating to it's courses, with a separate thread for each exercise. (This is one of Duo's best features IMHO.) Not that you aren't welcome to ask here of course.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that both answers shouldn't be accepted. The word "surrender" has several meanings in English; you can "surrender your passport", "surrender a battle", or "surrender yourself" to the police. (Wikitionary lists 7 meanings in all.) I don't think you can determine the exact meaning of "I will not surrender" without context. Without knowing the exact meaning, it's hard to determine the most appropriate translation.

Comment: Since there is no object, I doubt it is surrendering a passport. I went with the most obvious choice.

Comment: @RDBury: Note that at least among the examples you enumerate, none would be expressed as "mich aufgeben".

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: As a reflexive verb, *aufgeben* means "to give up" according to Wiktionary, but it's not clear on which meaning of "give up" they're referring to. From the usage examples I've seen it's more along the lines of 'to quit", "to admit defeat" or perhaps "to lose hope", and you're right, these would rarely be phrased as "to surrender".

Comment: @RDBury: Are you referring to [this page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aufgeben)? It mentions reflexivity of "aufgeben" only once, and with a very specific meaning (the one outlined by [Crystal Case](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/67193/5999). In general, "aufgeben" in the sense of "to give up", "to quit", etc. is *not* used reflexively. (Not to be confused with "sich ergeben", which absolutely means "to surrender" (in the context of a battle or other physical fight) and is reflexive.)

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Yes, that was the page I was looking at. It's a bit frustrating because Wiktionary is vague on the meaning, and the other references I usually go to aren't helping much either. It does seem to have a reflexive meaning though, for example, from the German subtitles to the movie "Hud": *Wie hast du ihm geholfen, Hud? lndem du ihn verraten wolltest und ihm allen Mut nahmst? lndem du ihn dazu brachtest sich aufzugeben? lst das deine Hilfe?*

Comment: @RDBury: Well, that's the one reflexive meaning mentioned above, and in Crystal Case's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you can translate "I will not surrender" word by word -> "Ich werde nicht aufgeben".
With "mich" you change the meaning by adding "myself". Your answer translates into "I will not surrender myself" or with better wording "I will not give up on myself".

Comment: Better: "I will not give myself up".

Answer (score 3):

> Ich werde mich nicht aufgeben.

Comes from *jmdn. aufgeben*, meaning *to forsake sb*.

> Ich werde nicht aufgeben.

This comes from *aufgeben* meaning to surrender.